# Python Modules in the Blender Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine

I was writing a Python script for the Blender Game Engine, and I noticed that any time I imported a module other than the bge, the rest of my script wouldn't run.  I was planning on using the random module to place my enemies in random positions throughout the game.  If you could explain how to get around this problem, that would be great!

Comment: The script will stop at an error, is there any error output in the console? Maybe the module name has a typo.